# Python interacting with OS X - is it possible?

Tags: python, macos

I'll explain my question: is it possible to write a Python script which interacts with OS X architecture in a *high-level* way?
For example, can I gain control on Mac OS X windows **resizing** from a Python script? Are there modules for that? I'm not finding any.

To push things even further, would I be able to control keyboard shortcuts too? I mean, with Python, could I write a script that opens a terminal window everytime I type `cmd + Enter` *from wherever I am* in that moment, as if it was a system shortcut (**Awesome WM** style, if you know what I'm talking about)?

Hope I've been clear.

Comment: There is a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851804/how-to-convert-a-string-into-a-set-of-keystrokes-in-python-on-osx) about python and calling into C code to trigger keyevents

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd one you can't do for sure, since the events are grabbed by other processes.
You should look for a osx specific library for doing that and then write a python wrapper around it.

Comment: I was playing around with AppleScript to get this work done, but I really don't like the language nor the way Apple describes it in its developer site docs. Any idea about the libs you're talking about?

Comment: @whatyouhide: Well what about [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/index.html)?